# Logtash file parsing containing inconsistent delimiter and columns names

Tags: logstash

I have a file with contents

```
Columns = Name|Age|Gender
Delimiter = |
[DATA]
John|23|M
Jane|25|F

Columns = Country,State
Delimiter = ,
[DATA]
Canada,Ontario
USA,Nevada
```

I want a Logstash parser which uses the information above each [DATA] section to extract the fields in each [DATA] section. Sample expected output is below

```
{
"message": "John|23|M",
"Name": "John",
"Age": "23",
"Gender": "M"
},
{
"message": "Canada,Ontario",
"Country": "Canada",
"State": "Ontario"
}
```

Comment: I got a solution after going to some other communities. Refer to https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parsing-file-containing-sectional-metadata-and-data/354020/3 for solution to this problem.